# Paypal IPN Initial and Subsequent Responses

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm working on a project that deals with different payments using Paypal, that is,

- one-time payments
- subscriptions
- instalments

I'm just curious about these issues:

1. Is the notification URL being called after a buyer is auto-debited for each subscription/instalment cycle (e.g. monthly, annual, etc.)?
2. If #1 is true, is there a difference in the IPN response for the initial subscription/instalment payment and subsequent payments for that same order?
3. If #1 and #2 are true, can you give me a sample response string to demonstrate the difference?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: https://www.paypal.com/nz/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-subscriptions-outside answers your questions.

Comment: thanks. that really helps. can you post your comment as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Below are additional variables that are used for Instant Payment
>   Notifications for Subscriptions and Recurring Payments

https://www.paypal.com/nz/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-subscriptions-outside

Comment: Thank you very much. That is a really great help.